# os.rename returning winerror 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to a script to rename to the date that it was sent as an email(which is the first part of the script but doesn't matter for this part) then to rename, and sort it into a 'Complete' folder. This is what my code looks like

Edit - I have all the imported stuff way up at the top and i didnt show it, but i assume i have the right stuff imported if you would like to see just ask

```
dir5 = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\Test\\AmLit"
dir6 = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\Test\\History"
dir7 = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\Test\\MultiLit"
dir8 = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\Test\\Physics"
dir5_final = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\TestMove\\AmLit"
dir6_final = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\TestMove\\History"
dir7_final = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\TestMove\\MultiLit"
dir8_final = "C:\\Users\\Michael D\\Documents\\TestMove\\Physics"


now = datetime.datetime.now()
now1 = (str(now.day) + '/' + str(now.month) + '/' + str(now.year))

dir5_files = os.listdir(dir5)
dir6_files = os.listdir(dir6)
dir7_files = os.listdir(dir7)
dir8_files = os.listdir(dir8)

for f in dir5_files:
    if (f.startswith("A") or f.startswith("a")):
        os.rename(f, now1 + " " + f)
```

but i keep getting this error

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Michael D/Documents/Coding/Schoolwork Email/Email Sender Beta 1.7.21.9.16.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael D/Documents/Coding/Schoolwork Email/Email Sender Beta 1.7.21.9.16.py", line 148, in <module>
    os.rename(f, now1 + " " + f)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'A Test.txt' -> '21/9/2016 A Test.txt'
```

any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not getting the full path from `os.listdir()`, either change working directory or give the full path to `rename()`.

Answer (score 4):

2 errors:

1. You are not in the current directory
2. You just cannot have slashes in the names. The filesystem won't allow it as it is (alternately) used to separate path parts.

First, generate the date directly with underscores:

```
now1 = (str(now.day) + '_' + str(now.month) + '_' + str(now.year))
```

Then replace

```
os.rename(f, now1 + " " + f)
```

by

```
os.rename(os.path.join(dir5,f), os.path.join(dir5,now1.replace("/","_") + " " + f))
```

and `A Test.txt` would be renamed to `21_9_2016 A Test.txt` in the directory you specified.